# Can we automate moves in third person shooter games?

Tags: python, game-development, pyautogui

I have used pyautogui to press keys automatically for small games.
But to implement my project on third person shooter games, I need to control the player with w-a-s-d. I tried some things like

```
for i in range(10): 
    pyautogui.press("w")
```

and

```
 pyautogui.keyDown("w")
 time.sleep(10)
 pyautogui.keyUp("w")
```

But none works for me, the player doesn't move.
It works completely fine with other games with w-a-s-d controls but not for third person shooter?

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Some third party games block the use of third party software like pyautogui, Not sure how they do it, has something to do with restricting win32. There are ways around it, but what is the game and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was trying to implement IOT applications for playing a game, specifically valorant, and i wanted to control the player using hand movements, so i was using pyautogui to control w-a-s-d keys, the controls works well in notepad or small games like subway surfers but can not handle any third person shooter games.